# Install Nginx ingress on Openshift cluster

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I know this is an obvious question regarding Kubernetes and Nginx ingress. But, I just couldn't install Nginx ingress on my Openshift cluster.

[Openshift docs](https://www.nginx.com/blog/getting-started-nginx-ingress-operator-red-hat-openshift/) tells that Nginx can be installed from the Operator hub. But, when searching for Nginx I can't find it.

[image]

I have found Openshift documentation- [Nginx Operator provided by the Operator SDK.](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/operators/operator_sdk/osdk-helm.html#osdk-building-helm-operator_osdk-helm), Which shows how to create a new Nginx operator from scratch.

Also, I have tried to install Nginx ingress using a helm chart but no luck as well. Got tons of exceptions related to wrong annotations and missing policies.

My goal is to install Nginx ingress against my Openshift cluster with the minimum effort as possible.
Or, if there is an easier and stable way to install resource who equivalent to Nginx aginst Opensihft.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Openshift version?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu 4.4.17

Answer (score 0):

it seems that this problem is just related to your openshift operator hub in your cluster. make sure that you have those operator in your cluster :
Red Hat Operators

- Certified Operators
- Community Operators
- Redhat Operators

and then you can install nginx operator without problems.
for more information you can take a look at openshift docs.
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/applications/operators/olm-adding-operators-to-cluster.html

I hope that was helpful.